# Automated Clonezilla backup and GPG encryption

Tags: gpg, clonezilla

I have a desktop Linux system which I regularly create clones of to a local RAID-6 array using Clonezilla.

It's proven to be quite a hassle to walk through the backup process, which takes quite a few steps:

1. Select Dvorak as the Keyboard Layout
2. Mount the RAID-6 array.
3. Select to backup the entire array and to check it.
4. Select compression options.
5. Confirm that everything is good and to proceed with the backup.

I'd like to configure a distribution that does all of this without any user input at boot.

How can I create a distribution for a thumb stick which automatically does all of this for me at boot without any prompts, then encrypts all of the backup files using GPG, then shuts down?

Comment: This guide from the Clonezilla website shows you how to do unattended runs: http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting

Comment: The clonezilla UI even tells you the command its actually running... But for backups, I suggest you switch to a backup program. That'll give you much better recovery options than Clonezilla.

Comment: @slm, want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Just posted the A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide from the Clonezilla website shows you how to do [unattended runs](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting).

*excerpt*

> By modifying the boot parameters in `syslinux/syslinux.cfg` (for live USB) or `isolinux/isolinux.cfg` (for CD), you can preseed most of the options so that Clonezilla live can do the job for you with less interactive steps, or it's possible to make it run in an unattended mode.

See this URL for the fully detailed steps.

- [In this example: Preseed some options to do restoring job after booting](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting)